# React Native App - react-navigation v5 can't unmount on blur

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I need screen to unmount whenever it goes out of focus. I am using a custom drawer and using props unmountOnBlur={true} and options={{unmountOnBlur: true} but its not working. What am i doing wrong or is there another way to accomplish this? I appreciate any help. Here is the relevant code:

```
<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawer {...props} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen
              name='Client Profile'
              component={ProfileStackNavigator}
              unmountOnBlur={true}
              options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
            />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Here is code on CustomDrawer.js :

```
<DrawerContentScrollView {...props} >
             <DrawerItem
                label='Profile'
                onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Client Profile')}
                unmountOnBlur={true}
                options={{unmountOnBlur: true}}
            />
</DrawerContentScrollView>
```

Comment: Any reason for not using DrawerItemList inside custom drawer?

Comment: yes, as i am rendering some UI in-between DrawerItems

Comment: DrawerItem is more of a listing than the actual navigation so that prop wont be passed

Comment: any other way to achieve that?

Comment: I dont see a way in the official docs maybe iterating the DrawerItemList havent tried it though

Comment: testing the same, it doesn't work, i'm using this on the login screen